# MySQL - Trouble to run a query

Tags: mysql, node.js, mariadb, sequelize.js, mysql-workbench

I have a query that I select some columns and I do `left join`. I'm using [MariaDB](https://mariadb.org/) at [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/).

### The Query that I trying to run

```sql
sequelize.query(`SELECT
        distinct av.idAnnouncementVehicles as id, 
        av.price, 
        CONCAT("https://autoparanaiba.s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/" , SUBSTRING_INDEX(ap.image, '.', 1) , '-355x180.' , SUBSTRING_INDEX(ap.image, '.', -1)) as  image,
        am.worked_hours, 
        am.year AS ano,
    md.description AS modelo, 
        bn.description AS marca, 
        fu.description AS combustivel,
        pw.description AS potência,
        tc.description AS tração
        FROM announcement_vehicles AS av 
        left join announcemment_photos AS ap on ap.annoucements_id = av.idAnnouncementVehicles
        left join persons AS pe on pe.id = av.personId 
        left join agricultural_machine AS am on am.agricultural_machine_id = av.itemId 
        left join itens AS it on it.id = av.itemId
        left join traction AS tc on tc.id = trac.traction_id
        left join power AS pw on pw.id = trac.power_id
        left join fuel AS fu on fu.id = trac.fuel_id 
        where it.type=${type} and (av.plans_id IS NOT NULL or pe.type = 'jud')
        group by av.idAnnouncementVehicles order by av.plans_id, av.idAnnouncementVehicles desc limit 8`, { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT })
        .then((result) => {
            return res.json({ success: true, result: result })
        }).catch((err) => {
            return res.status(400).json(err)
        })
```

This query is returning this error to me. But I have a similar query in the code that does not throw this error.

### The error

```
{
  "name": "SequelizeDatabaseError",
  "parent": {
    "code": "ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR",
    "errno": 1054,
    "sqlState": "42S22",
    "sqlMessage": "Unknown column 'md.description' in 'field list'",
```

### The similar query that I have

```sql
    sequelize.query(`SELECT
        distinct av.idAnnouncementVehicles as id, 
        av.price, 
        CONCAT("https://autoparanaiba.s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/" , SUBSTRING_INDEX(ap.image, '.', 1) , '-355x180.' , SUBSTRING_INDEX(ap.image, '.', -1)) as  image,
        ve.mileage, 
        fi.marca, 
        fi.name, 
    fi.ano, 
        fi.ano_modelo as modelo, 
        fu.description as combustivel  
        FROM announcement_vehicles as av 
        left join announcemment_photos as ap on ap.annoucements_id = av.idAnnouncementVehicles
        left join persons as pe on pe.id = av.personId 
        left join vehicles as ve on ve.item_id = av.itemId 
        left join itens as it on it.id = av.itemId
        left join fipe as fi on fi.id = ve.fipe_id 
        left join fuel as fu on fu.id = ve.fuel_id 
        left join color as co on co.id = ve.color_id 
        where it.type=${type} and (av.plans_id IS NOT NULL or pe.type = 'jud')
        group by av.idAnnouncementVehicles order by av.plans_id, av.idAnnouncementVehicles desc limit 8`, { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT })
        .then((result) => {
            return res.json({ success: true, result: result })
        }).catch((err) => {
            return res.status(400).json(err)
        })
```

Comment: There is no table aliased as md in your query - hence unknown column md.description

Comment: Neither do you have a table aliased as `bn`. And, presumably you know that `SELECT DISTINCT` applies to all columns of a result set.

Comment: @P.Salmon How can I aliase?

Comment: @O.Jones
What can I do to fix this?

Comment: You use table aliases all over your query so your comment on this is surprising. If you really don't know what an alias is then you should research the topic elsewhere. Your query is impossible to fix since we have no idea what it's supposed to do and reverse engineering from non working code is a mugs game.

Comment: @P.Salmon This query it's a simple I want to return all data types through the column ```type``` that is localized at  ```itens```  table. So at the ```announcement_vehicles``` table, there is the ```itemId```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the problem with this query

```sql
sequelize.query(`SELECT
        distinct av.idAnnouncementVehicles as id, 
        av.price, 
        CONCAT("https://autoparanaiba.s3-sa-east-1.amazonaws.com/" , SUBSTRING_INDEX(ap.image, '.', 1) , '-355x180.' , SUBSTRING_INDEX(ap.image, '.', -1)) as  image,
        am.worked_hours, 
        am.year AS ano,
    md.description AS modelo, 
        bn.description AS marca, 
        fu.description AS combustivel,
        pw.power AS potência,
        tc.description AS tração
        FROM announcement_vehicles AS av

        left join announcemment_photos AS ap on ap.annoucements_id = av.idAnnouncementVehicles
        left join persons AS pe on pe.id = av.personId

        left join agricultural_machine AS am on am.agricultural_machine_id = av.itemId 
        left join model_agricultural_machine as md on md.id = am.model_agricultural_machine_id
        left join brand_agricultural_machine as bn on bn.id = am.brand_agricultural_machine_id

        left join tractor as trc on trc.tractor_id = am.agricultural_machine_id
        left join power as pw on pw.id = trc.power_id


        left join itens AS it on it.id = av.itemId
        left join traction AS tc on tc.id = trc.traction_id

        left join fuel AS fu on fu.id = trc.fuel_id 

        where it.type=${type} and (av.plans_id IS NOT NULL or pe.type = 'jud')
        group by av.idAnnouncementVehicles order by av.plans_id, av.idAnnouncementVehicles desc limit 8`, { type: sequelize.QueryTypes.SELECT })
        .then((result) => {
            return res.json({ success: true, result: result })
        }).catch((err) => {
            return res.status(400).json(err)
        })
```